# How to apply a custom local/offline map style to an OpenLayers Map

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, openlayers, openmaptiles

I have a local webpage as part of a larger desktop application. I want to change the default style of the Open Layer map to ["Klokantech Basic"](https://github.com/openmaptiles/klokantech-basic-gl-style). I've downloaded a copy of the style JSON but struggeerling to apply it to the map. Currently my code looks like:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }), vectorLayer],
        target: 'map',
        style: './mapStyle.json',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.146953, 51.493758]),
            zoom: 15
        })
```

But setting a style isn't working, I've looked online and there appears to be Map Box, this however uses an API key, something which I don't want to use/ maintain.

The whole page and its resources are stored locally, is there any way of referencing the local style file without an API?

[Here is my current code.](https://github.com/jfoot/LocalHTMLMap)

Answer (score 0):

The mapbox style is for vector tile source and I pretend you use it for your vector layer.

Openlayers don't seem to support the Mapbox style for MVT. It use a style function to apply to the vector tile.You can see here a [exemple](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles-advanced.html) of how Openlayers make [style function](https://openlayers.org/en/v5.1.3/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js) for vector tiles.

Comment: As you stated, OpenLayers does not support Mapbox style directly but using `ol-mapbox-style` https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-style (a plugin), it does by converting these styles to OpenLayers styling syntax

Comment: It shoud be explained how to migrate the styles. Answer "use a plugin" is not ab answer. The plugin needs some online resources so in you prapare a map for localhost or intranet purposes it won't be a solution.